References for some Fibonacci numbers identities
I found the following 9 identities in OEIS (A000045 Section Formula):

\begin{align}
F_{nm} = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} F_{n-1}^{k} F_{n}^{m-k} F_{m-k}.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
F_{2^{n}} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-2} a_{i},  \hspace{3mm} a_{i}= a_{i-1}^{2} -2 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
F_{n+1} = 2^{n} \sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^{n} \cos^{2} \frac{k \pi}{n+1} + \frac{1}{4} } 
\end{align}

\begin{align}F_{n} = F_{n+2}-1 + F_{n+1}^{4} + 2(F_{n+1}^{3} F_{n+2}) - (F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^{2} - 2F_{n+1}F_{n-2}^{3} + F_{n+2}^{4}. \end{align}

\begin{align} \frac{F_{n+3}^{2} - F_{n+1}^{2}}{F_{n+2}} = F_{n+3} + F_{n+1}. \end{align}

\begin{align} F_{2n} = F_{n+2}^{2} - F_{n+1}^{2} - 2F_{n}^{2}. \end{align}

\begin{align} F_{n} = \frac{F_{2n+k+1} - F_{n+1} F_{n+k+1}}{F_{n+k}}, \hspace{3mm} k\geq 0. \end{align}

\begin{align} F_{n+10} = 11F_{n+5} + F_{n}\end{align}

\begin{align} F_{n} = 4F_{n-3} + F_{n-6}, \hspace{3mm} n\geq 6\end{align}


I tried to find papers/books in which these identities are proved, but without success.
Any help would be appreciated.

For the first one: d'Ocagne's identity

For the second one, you need a base case for the recursion.  $a_0 = 3$ does it.   The sequence of $a_i$, namely $3, 7, 47, 2207, \ldots$ is A001566.  That references a paper: A. V. Aho and N. J. A. Sloane, Some doubly exponential sequences, Fibonacci Quarterly, Vol. 11, No. 4 (1973), pp. 429-437 (https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/11-4/aho-a.pdf).  I can't quite work out the proof of the second identity from that paper but it may be of interest.

Fibonacci and Lucas Numbers, and the Golden Section, Steven Vajda, Dover, 1986, and Fibonacci and Golden Ratio Formulae, R. Knott, https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/fibFormulae.html.

Can you say what the goal of tracking down the references is? If it's verification you want, then there are easier approaches; for example, checking identities 4-9 is a matter of substituting the formula and simplifying. (It is not always the easiest method, but it's the one that requires the least creativity.)

To give some context, which "papers/books" did you read?

@MishaLavrov I am looking for references for proofs of these identities because I want to include proofs of them in my lecture next week. I know there are non-creative ways of proving them, but I am interested if there are any other ways. Also, I am sure I won't be able to prove first four identities by myself.

@Somos I searched through Fobonacci quarterly and on google schoolar (for example, I searched Fibonacci numbers cosine identity).

5 and 6 are both related to the fact that $F_{2n} = F_nL_n$ and the answer I gave here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5007877/1288180


\begin{align}
F_{nm} = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} F_{n-1}^{k} F_{n}^{m-k} F_{m-k}.
\end{align}

This paper proves that
$$F_{kn+c}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom kiF_{c-i}F_n^iF_{n+1}^{k-i}$$
You can set $c=k$ with $n\to n-1$.


\begin{align}
F_{2^{n}} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-2} a_{i},  \hspace{3mm} a_{i}= a_{i-1}^{2} -2 
\end{align}

From $a_{i}= a_{i-1}^{2} -2$ with $a_0=F_{2^2}=3$, one can prove that $a_i=L_{2^{i+1}}$ where $L_j$ is Lucas numbers. (You can use the fact that $L_{2n}=L_n^2-2(-1)^n$.)
This paper proves in Lemma 2 that
$$F_{2^{n}} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-2} L_{2^{i+1}}$$


\begin{align}
F_{n+1} = 2^{n} \sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^{n} \cos^{2} \frac{k \pi}{n+1} + \frac{1}{4} } 
\end{align}

This answer proves that
$$F_n^2 = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(3 + 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\right)$$
You can use $\cos 2A=2\cos^2A-1$ with $n\to n+1$.


\begin{align}F_{n} = F_{n+2}-1 + F_{n+1}^{4} + 2(F_{n+1}^{3} F_{n+2}) - (F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^{2} - 2F_{n+1}F_{n-2}^{3} + F_{n+2}^{4}. \end{align}

I think you have typos. It should be
$$F_{n} = F_{n+2}-1 + F_{n+1}^{4} + 2(F_{n+1}^{3} F_{n+2}) - (F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^{2} - 2F_{n+1}F_{n\color{red}+2}^{3} + F_{n+2}^{4}\color{red}{-F_{n+1}}$$
Let $F_n=a,F_{n+1}=b$. Then, since $F_{n+2}=a+b$ and $\color{red}{b^2}=ab+a^2+(-1)^n$ (which is equivalent to $F_{n+1}F_{n-1}=F_n^2+(-1)^n$, and see here), we have
$$\begin{align}RHS&=a^4+a-1+2a^3b
\\&\qquad +\color{red}{b^2}( - a^2- 2 a b  + \color{red}{b^2})
\\&=a^4+a-1+2a^3b
\\&\qquad +(ab+a^2+(-1)^n)(-ab+(-1)^n)
\\&=a+a^2(\underbrace{a^2+ a b + (-1)^n-\color{red}{b^2}}_{=0})
\\&=a\end{align}$$


\begin{align} \frac{F_{n+3}^{2} - F_{n+1}^{2}}{F_{n+2}} = F_{n+3} + F_{n+1}. \end{align}

We have
$$LHS=\frac{(F_{n+3}+F_{n+1})(F_{n+3}-F_{n+1})}{F_{n+2}}=RHS$$
since $F_{n+3}-F_{n+1}=F_{n+2}$.


\begin{align} F_{2n} = F_{n+2}^{2} - F_{n+1}^{2} - 2F_{n}^{2}. \end{align}

We have
$$\begin{align}RHS&=(F_{n+1}+F_n)^2-F_{n+1}^2-2F_n^2
\\&=2F_nF_{n+1}-F_n^2
\\&=F_n(F_{n+1}+F_{n+1}-F_n)
\\&=F_n(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1})\end{align}$$
Now, see here.


\begin{align} F_{n} = \frac{F_{2n+k+1} - F_{n+1} F_{n+k+1}}{F_{n+k}}, \hspace{3mm} k\geq 0. \end{align}

It is sufficient to prove
$$F_{n+m} = F_nF_{m+1} + F_{n-1}F_m$$
(see for example here)


\begin{align} F_{n+10} = 11F_{n+5} + F_{n}\end{align}

Using $F_N=F_{N-1}+F_{N-2}$, we have
$$\begin{align}F_{n+10}&=F_{n+9}+F_{n+8}
\\&=(F_{n+8}+F_{n+7})+(F_{n+7}+F_{n+6})
\\&=F_{n+8}+2F_{n+7}+F_{n+6}
\\&=(F_{n+7}+F_{n+6})+2(F_{n+6}+F_{n+5})
\\&\qquad +(F_{n+5}+F_{n+4})
\\&=F_{n+7}+3F_{n+6}+3F_{n+5}+F_{n+4}
\\&=(F_{n+6}+F_{n+5})+3(F_{n+5}+F_{n+4})
\\&\qquad +3F_{n+5}+(F_{n+3}+F_{n+2})
\\&=F_{n+6}+7F_{n+5}+3F_{n+4}+F_{n+3}+F_{n+2}
\\&=(F_{n+5}+F_{n+4})+7F_{n+5}+3F_{n+4}
\\&\qquad +(F_{n+5}-F_{n+4})+(F_{n+1}+F_{n})
\\&=9F_{n+5}+3F_{n+4}+F_{n+1}+F_n
\\&=9F_{n+5}+3F_{n+4}+F_{n+3}-F_{n+2}+F_n
\\&=9F_{n+5}+3F_{n+4}+(F_{n+5}-F_{n+4})
\\&\qquad -(F_{n+4}-F_{n+3})+F_n
\\&=10F_{n+5}+\underbrace{F_{n+4}+F_{n+3}}_{=F_{n+5}}+F_n
\\&=11F_{n+5}+F_n\end{align}$$


\begin{align} F_{n} = 4F_{n-3} + F_{n-6}, \hspace{3mm} n\geq 6\end{align}

Using $F_N=F_{N-1}+F_{N-2}$, we have
$$\begin{align}F_n&=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}
\\&=(F_{n-2}+F_{n-3})+(F_{n-3}+F_{n-4})
\\&=F_{n-2}+2F_{n-3}+F_{n-4}
\\&=(F_{n-3}+F_{n-4})+2F_{n-3}+(F_{n-5}+F_{n-6})
\\&=3F_{n-3}+\underbrace{F_{n-4}+F_{n-5}}_{=F_{n-3}}+F_{n-6}
\\&=4F_{n-3}+F_{n-6}\end{align}$$

I recommend using the following two books:
Fibonacci and Lucas Numbers with Applications, Volume 1 (Pure and Applied Mathematics: A Wiley Series of Texts, Monographs and Tracts)
Fibonacci and Lucas Numbers with Applications, Volume 2 (Pure and Applied Mathematics: A Wiley Series of Texts, Monographs and Tracts)
